# How do I get the statue in South Central?

Tags: sleeping-dogs

Thanks to my newly acquired perk of statues showing up on my minimap, I know that there is a statue in the southern part of the central district. Right around here:
[image: Map of status location]

After climbing up a construction site and running all over the place, I can see the statue inside of this building:
[image: Statue inside building]

Upon realizing that I couldn't enter the building through the doors, I tried to return to the ledge that I came from, but alas, I can't climb back up:
[image: Unclimbable ledge]

Where did I go wrong in tracking down the statue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Jade statue is not available until you have reached mission [Conflicted Loyalties](http://www.ign.com/wikis/sleeping-dogs/Conflicted_Loyalties). So the only way to get this statue is to progress with the main story line.

Comment: Ahh, I'm a couple quests away from that. Once I get past that quest and confirm, I'll accept this. Thanks!

Comment: This is, in fact, the correct answer. Thanks, @neo!

Comment: Wow, thanks! I lost time to try to jump everywhere...

Comment: Don't you hate it when games show you things like that when you can't possibly get them yet? What a terrible user experience design.